# Get the "real" source code from a website

Tags: html, google-chrome

I've got a problem getting the "real" source code from a website:

http://sirius.searates.com/explorer

Trying it the normal way (view-source:) via Chrome I get a different result than trying it by using inspect elements function. And the code which I can see (using that function) is the one that I would like to have... How is that possible to get this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens because the UI is actually generated by a client-side Javascript utility.

In this case, most of the screen is generated by [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/), and a few elements are generated/modified by [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

The DOM inspector will always give you the "current" view of the HTML, while the view source gives you the "initial" view. Since view source does not run the Javascript utilities, much of the UI is never generated.

To get the most up-to-date (HTML) source, you can use the DOM inspector to find the root html node, right-click and select "Edit as HTML". Then select-all and copy/paste into your favorite text editor.

Note, though, that this will only give you a snapshot of the page. Most modern web pages are really browser applications and the HTML is just one part of the whole. Copy/pasting the HTML will not give you a fully functional page.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Is there any way to do this automatically with VBA, so opening the DOM inspector and copying the content, which can be copied?

Comment: With [VBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications)? Why would you be using VBA?

Comment: I'm pretty sure setting up any integration between Chrome and VBA would be extremely complicated, and I'm not sure why you'd want to do it. You'd almost certainly need to write your own COM objects in .NET or C.

Comment: I need 50 000 shipping-distances between the capitals of the world for my BA-thesis in a table (EXCEL) and to get them I need the source code which is including the distance values. The "initial" source code unfortunately doesn't include these, but the code I get with DOM inspector does...

Comment: I once created something like that in Excel. It took me (a professional programmer with a decade of experience) about a week to write. I had to do it in C# (although VB.NET or F# would work) and then use the code as a custom plugin. VBA is restrictive by design to make it harder for hackers to damage your system. Since you clearly don't understand much about web services, I'd recommend you find a developer to help you or find a pre-made list somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can get real-time html with this url,bookmark this url:

```
javascript:document.write('<textarea width="400">'+document.body.innerHTML+'</textarea>');
```